# Listar nombres de las ventanas abiertas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy tratando de obtener el nombre de las ventanas abiertas en mi escritorio o bien hacer un clic a la esa ventana y obtener su nombre en un listview de mi aplicación Windows Forms C#.

He estado intentando con este código, pero no me devuelve nada en el listview, tampoco me da error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetCaptionOfActiveWindow();
    }

    private void GetCaptionOfActiveWindow()
    {
        Process[] processes =
        Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(p.MainWindowTitle);
        }
    }
```

[image: Ventana]

[image: NuevaImagen]
Alguna idea de como poder hacer esto?

Espero puedan ayudarme.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `Process.GetProcesses()` que te retornara todas las aplicaciones activas.

`Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")` retorna todos procesos que en el nombre contengan la palabra `explorer`, no los procesos que esten dentro del explorer.

Comment: Si me funciona, solo una pregunta porque lista demasiados Ítems vacíos en el listView?
Así como la nueva imagen que agregue a la pregunta.
@Einer

Comment: Puede ser debido a que el desarrollador haya ignorado asignarle un nombre a la ventana.